# Is it possible to get Sign of an integer nonnegative number using 4 basic operations?

Tags: integers

I need to get Sign of an integer nonnegative number using 4 basic math operations (summation, subtraction, multiplication, division). Abs or other functions are not allowed. How can I do this?

Comment: By 4 basic math ops do you mean multiplication, addition, subtraction, division?

Comment: Yes they are. I have updated the question adding them.

Answer (score 2):

Any such function would be, by definition, the restriction to the natural numbers of some rational function $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{\text{a few points}\}\to \Bbb R$, and it ought to be $1$ on all natural numbers except $0$, and be $0$ in $0$. This cannot be the case, because the constant $1$ is a rational function and two distinct rational functions can only coincide on finitely many points.

Comment: This assumes a procedure independent of such number, no? As in, the rational function is fixed beforehand.

Comment: @guidoar I mean, that seems to be the case, no? It strikes me as obvious that the OP wants a rational function that works for all natural numbers, because if you could make cases, then take $0$ in $0$ and  $1$ elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed, haha.  +1